# String cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method

Tags: kotlin, dagger-hilt

I'm trying to use `ActivityScoped` and `ActivityComponent` in a simple project, but i was getting below error

```
@javax.inject.Named("String2") java.lang.String cannot be provided without an 
@Provides-annotated method.
public abstract static class SingletonC implements BaseApplication_GeneratedInjector,
@javax.inject.Named("String2") java.lang.String is injected at
      com.example.hiltoplayground.TestViewModel(testString)
  com.example.hiltoplayground.TestViewModel is injected at
      com.example.hiltoplayground.TestViewModel_HiltModules.BindsModule.binds(vm)
  @dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.HiltViewModelMap 
 java.util.Map<java.lang.String,javax.inject.Provider<androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel>> 
 is requested at
      dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.HiltViewModelFactory.ViewModelFactoriesEntryPoint.getHiltViewModelMap() [com.example.hiltoplayground.BaseApplication_HiltComponents.SingletonC → com.example.hiltoplayground.BaseApplication_HiltComponents.ActivityRetainedC → com.example.hiltoplayground.BaseApplication_HiltComponents.ViewModelC]
```

But if i use `SingletonComponent` and `@Singleton` it runs perfect,  no issue.

Here is the affected module

```
@Module
@InstallIn(ActivityComponent::class)
object MainModule {

    @ActivityScoped
    @Provides
    @Named("String2")
    fun provideTestString2 (
        @ApplicationContext context: Context
    ) = context.getString(R.string.string_inject)
}
```

Below is the ViewModel (No problem here i guess)

```
@HiltViewModel
class TestViewModel @Inject constructor(
    @Named("String2") testString: String): ViewModel() {

        init{
            Log.d("String2Message","Show $testString")
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `@ActivityRetainedScoped` in place of `@ActivityScoped` and make `@InstallIn(ActivityRetainedComponent::class)` from `@InstallIn(ActivityComponent::class)`.